Science fiction novel, probably from the 2000s. Main character on mission on Earth for Moon Queen. Broken America and "seal-people"
I am looking for a science fiction novel, probably from the 2000s. It was written in a style similar to Neal Stephenson, Kim Stanley Robinson or Ben Bova.
From what I recall it starts in a dual person spaceship, with a human and a human-descendent, a "Belter" or maybe "Selenite". The human receives a call from a high ranking lunar "royalty" female, with whom he had an affair in the past. Her name may be Lillysaire or similar.
I think he interrupts the mission to go to her, and is tasked by her, due to some feeling of responsibility, or maybe love and devotion, to do something on Earth for her. I think it had something to do with an AI, but don't recall exactly. He is also assigned an AI to help him, but I don't think he is aware of that at the time.
On Earth he liaisons with a female human who I think shares some of his goals. I also recall that they are being followed by Earth agencies or AI that manage most of Earth's affairs. At some point they have to go through part of central USA, that has become a sort of reservation (Brave New World style) where you have to sign documents stating that you enter on your own free will and that human rights are not guaranteed inside.
The Inside is ruled by American descendants who are extremely libertarian, or at some point very xenophobic, or don't have rights for women, or the rule is by might; it varies according to the zone/small fiefdom you are in.
The rising sea levels and the existence or engineered humans like "seal-people" and their rights are also important plot points. I don't recall the ending. For some reason it felt something that was part of a larger series/universe, but that is only a feeling.

The Lunar Chronicles by Marissa Meyer. It's been a while since I read the series, so I am not sure about the exact book. But it might be Cinder based on your description. It is also the first book in the series.
The story felt similar but may not be the exact one. The Lunar Chronicles is a fairytale retelling series, but in a futuristic world inspired by Star Wars/Star Trek. Cinder is a cyborg living in futuristic Beijing (Eastern Commonwealth) with her stepsisters and stepmother. Kai is the prince and worried due to an epidemic in his empire. Cinder is immune to the disease. Later, it is found that she is immune, as she is 'Lunar'.
Backstory: Lunar Queen, Cinder's aunt, jealous of her sister's beauty and popularity, kills her sister and tries to kill her niece in the curb. Someone saves her and brings her to Earth (thus a cyborg after the accident).
Relevance to the question: There are 'selenites' or humans/wolf breeds mentioned in another part of the series (Scarlet). There is a royal bot who helps Kai and also Cinder. There is another main character from 'Cress' that is flying in a spacecraft. The protagonist against her, Carswell Thorne, rescues Cinder with Cress, Bot, and Kai's help.
Many other things are going on, like the lunar rebellion. Lunar Queen trying to take control of the earth. Hence, the wolf/human breed. Another Easter egg is Cinder being immune to epidemic as she is lunar, and the epidemic was engineered/initiated on the orders of Lunar Queens as a bio weapon against Earth.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve your answer if you [edit] it to describe the work more, especially how it matches the question.
